# Outputs of Granger causality and FEVD are opposite of each other

Tags: r, vector-autoregression, cointegration, granger-causality

This is regarding cointegration or VAR analysis of bivariate systems. The Granger causality will either say that instrument 1 (say fund) and instrument 2 (say index) are either not Granger causing each other or that the instrument 2 is Granger causing instrument 1.

However, when I see the FEVD output, more than 90% of FEV of index is attributed to fund. This happens regardless of the existence of cointegration between the two instruments. In other words, set1 is cointegrated and an ECM is estimated and set2 is not cointegrated and a VAR in differences is estimated.

This means that the FEVD and Granger causality outputs are showing opposite results. How do I resolve this?

I am using "Analysis of Integrated and cointegrated time Series with R" by Bernhard Pfaff for the R code.

[image: FEVD output]

R code given below:

```r
comboFEVD1<-tsDyn::fevd(var_model_diff1,n.ahead = 10)
plot(comboFEVD1)

## Output from R
# Screenshot uploaded

tsVAR <- vars::VAR(ret_df1, p = 2)
vars::causality(tsVAR, cause = "dindex")$Granger

## Output from R
## Granger causality H0: dindex do not Granger-cause dfund
##
## data: VAR object tsVAR
## F-Test = 7.6993, df1 = 2, df2 = 2980, p-value = 0.0004622

vars::causality(tsVAR, cause = "dfund")$Granger

## Output from R
## Granger causality H0: dfund do not Granger-cause dindex
##
## data: VAR object tsVAR
## F-Test = 4.6794, df1 = 2, df2 = 2980, p-value = 0.009353
```

Comment: May be helpful to share the output/code from R to illustrate where the problem lies.

Comment: @ShawnHemelstrand .. code and fevd output image attached. While the granger causality output here shows bi-directional causality, the FEVD from VAR is the same. The fund "dictates" the index. I would be grateful for any pointers.

Comment: Granger is a surname, so the first letter is capitalized.

Answer (score 0):

dfund takes the largest share of explaining the variance, but that doesn't mean that there is no statistical significance for dindex explaining some of the variance as well.

The fevd graph expresses the relative effect sizes, the F-test expresses the statistical significance of those effect sizes.

---

Asside from the above issue, while trying to replicate your result, I came across an interesting effect.

While trying to make a situation where A is dominating the FEVD, but B is the most significant for the Granger causality test, I added a correlated noise term ($u_{1,t}$ is added to both vector elements)

$$\begin{array}{}
y_{1,t} &=& 0.99 y_{2,t-1} + 0.1 u_{1,t}+1 u_{1,t}\\
y_{2,t} &=& 0.99 y_{2,t-1} + 0.1 u_{2,t}+1 u_{1,t} 
\end{array} $$

Then this will be interpreted as A being strongest in FEVD. However when I switch the columns, then B is suddenly the strongest.

```
n = 1000
set.seed(1)
library(vars, quietly = TRUE)

# create some autocorrelated vector y
# based on error terms u

   ### empty matrix
y = matrix(rep(NA,2*n),n)
colnames(y) = c("A","B")

   ### start
y[1,] = c(0,0)
y[2,] = c(0,0)

   ### errors
u = matrix(rnorm(2*n),n)


   ### compute timeseries
for (i in 3:n) {
    y[i,] =  y[i-1,1] * c(0.0,0.0) +
             y[i-2,1] * c(0.0,0.0) +
             y[i-1,2] * c(0.99,0.99) + 
             y[i-2,2] * c(0.0,0.0) + 
             0.1*u[i,] + u[i,1]*c(1,1)
}


mod <- VAR(y, p = 2)

### p-value for cause A is 0.8846
causality(mod, cause = "A")$Granger
### p-value for cause B is 0.03045
causality(mod, cause = "B")$Granger

### influence of A is largest
combo<-tsDyn::fevd(mod,n.ahead = 10)
plot(combo)

### switch columns
### now the influence of B is largest
y = y[,c(2,1)]
y[1:10,]
mod <- VAR(y, p = 2)
combo<-tsDyn::fevd(mod,n.ahead = 10)
plot(combo)
```

Comment: The apparent problem seems to be that an effect that is not statistically significant in the Granger test overwhelmingly dominates in the FEVD. That is pretty counterintuitive. It was a long time since I looked into FEVD, but it could be that these two techniques (FECD and the F-test in Granger causality) are not measuring the exact same thing (whether in a relative or absolute way), so then there would not be a paradox.

Comment: @RichardHardy I see two times a low p-value. Doesn't that indicate statistical significant effects? It is just that the one effect is having a much stronger influence on the variance.

Comment: My bad. I misinterpreted the OPs statements at the top instead of paying more attention to the outputs at the bottom.

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus Does this mean that changing the order of variables during estimation will show different outputs. Then which output is "true" ? Regarding the granger causality significance, I have some sets where only dindex granger causes the dfund, but not the other way around, but in all cases, FEVD is always dominated by dfund. Right now, dfund is the first variable in the datasets

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus About the first part of your answer, does it mean FEVD is more dependable than Granger causality ? Meanwhile, I will redo the estimations by changing the order of variables and see what new surprises are waiting.

Comment: @significanceseeker Right now I do not exactly understand why the result changes when the columns are switched. It seems like the function might give the first column a special role in the model. I would have to look into the function more in detail and try to replicate it's result manually. But I in any case, I am not surprised about differences between FEVD (effect size) and granger causality (significance). Effect size and significance can be different. Also the causality is not entirely the same as the impact on variance. It can be that you have significant coëfficiënts  that cancel out.

Comment: I see now how the difference occurs: the model used by `tsdyn::VAR` is based on `tsDyn::VECM` which models $$x_t=ECT_x u_t+\alpha_x x_{t-1}+\beta_x y_{t-1}\\y_t=ECT_y u_t+\alpha_y x_{t-1}+\beta_y y_{t-1}$$ and I believe that $u_t=x_t +\beta y_t$. In that equation for the cointegrated term $u_t$ the first parameter is set fixed equal to 1, which is how a change of columns can have an influence. I do not know the details about this stuff, but I could detect this as the origin of the influence of switching the columns. I guess that a misspecification (x and y not cointegrated) can cause troubles.

Comment: That's not it after all. The same problem (influence of switching columns) occurs with VAR models generated with `tsDyn::lineVar`.